# How to get the column names of an Excel where the rows are blank Using Python

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

Out of multiple columns present in Excel sheet, Need to check find out the names of the specific columns for each rows from an excel sheet, and enter the name of the column in a different column. If none of the column is having any blank values it will be written as No Gaps.

Input Data:

```
col1    col2   col3   col4   col5   col6   Result
AB       BC     CD     EF     GH     IJ
AN       AP            AR     AS     AT
BP              BQ     BR            BT
BZ       BY                   BX     BW
CP       CQ     CR     CS
```

Expected Output:

```
Result

No Gaps  
col3 is not available
col2, col5 not available 
col3, col4 not available
col5, col6 not available
```

Script that i have tried so far:

```
if (df['col1'] || df['col2'] || df['col3'] || df['col4'] || df['col5'] || df['col6']).empty != True:
    df['Result']= "No Gaps"
else:
    df['Result']=
```

I am not getting how to go through each rows of the column and get the Column names for the blank rows written in ['Results'] column separated by ,

Comment: What is "blank" in this case? Since pandas shows empty values as `NaN`, or do you mean empty string like `''`

Comment: @Erfan - Blank is NaN only,

Answer (score 6, accepted):

With **[`df.dot`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.dot.html)** and **[`np.where`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.where.html)** and some string addition you can achieve this.

**Note:** *If `Result` column already exists in your df, drop it first*

If your blanks are blank strings, you can do:

```
u = df.eq('').dot(df.columns+",").str.rstrip(",")
out = df.assign(Result=np.where(u.ne(''),u.add(" not available"),"No Gaps"))
```

If they are `nan`:

```
u = df.isna().dot(df.columns+",").str.rstrip(",")
out = df.assign(Result=np.where(u.ne(''),u.add(" not available"),"No Gaps"))
```

---

```
print(out)

  col1 col2 col3 col4 col5 col6                   Result
0   AB   BC   CD   EF   GH   IJ                  No Gaps
1   AN   AP  NaN   AR   AS   AT       col3 not available
2   BP  NaN   BQ   BR  NaN   BT  col2,col5 not available
3   BZ   BY  NaN  NaN   BX   BW  col3,col4 not available
4   CP   CQ   CR   CS  NaN  NaN  col5,col6 not available
```

Comment: @anky-  u = df.isna().dot(df.columns+",").str.rstrip(",") it will search for all the columns for null values, what needs to be done if we have to check for only 5 specific columns out of total 10 columns.

Comment: In variable a you have taken up 5 columns but while using it in variable u you kept only 3 columns, didn't understood.

Comment: @Manz That was a typo, sorry use `a = df[['col1','col2','col3','col4','col5']]` and then `u = a.isna().dot(a.columns+",").str.rstrip(",")` Basically use the same code with `a`- the subset instead of `df`- the full dataframe

Comment: Using u = a.isna().dot(a.columns+",").str.rstrip(","), It gives the output 'True' in each cases.

Comment: @Manz is your blanks `np.nan` or '' blank strings? I can test and see it works fine for me if the values are `np.nan`. Can you double check?

Comment: While printing the dataframe It gives NaN where there is no value. but after printing as print(df['Result']) it gives True in each case

Comment: @Manz Can you show me your code? I am doing `a = df[['col1','col2','col3','col4','col5']]` then `u = a.isna().dot(a.columns+",").str.rstrip(",")` and then `out = df.assign(Result=np.where(u.ne(''),u.add(" not available"),"No Gaps"))` and this works for me. There is no reason it shouldnt work if you are using the code correctly with the data you have shown us

Comment: .dot(a.columns+",") in this , is used for CSV file, I am using the data from Excel file, Is this the issue why i am facing the problem

Comment: The above suggested script is working perfect with rows with NaN  unless any Blank row comes up it doesn't gives the column name for that, how i can make the change , so that it can accept blank rows as well.

Comment: @Manz replace blank strings with np.nan, then use this.